# Is there any processor in NiFi which helps me add a unique identifier to each record?

Tags: apache-nifi

My processor is querying a DB2 table and loads data to S3 and then ingest it into Snowflake.
I have unique account numbers in my table and I need to add a column with unique identifier for each unique account number.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

${UUID()} returns random value, similar to de305d54-75b4-431b-adb2-eb6b9e546013

Pass this has attribute and then in content?

Comment: I saw this. Can I generate this for each record in the file? I thought it's generated for a single file not as an attribute for each record in the file.

Comment: You can use UpdateRecord with `Replacement Value Strategy` set to `Literal Value`, which supports Expression Language, where you can use the expression above

Comment: Yes it's file based, what I would do (if possible in your case): split your flowfile to have one record per flow file then use the UUID function and append it to your record. You should be able to rebuild the whole flow file with the adequate processor